# How to use Excel Vlookup based on two fields (Range)

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a vlookup formula that pulls the fee value from another sheet if the amount is between the Min and Max shown below: Any Help is appreciate.

My Code:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$S$70,3,FALSE)),"")


Min          Max          Fee
1            5000000      20
5000001      10000000     30    
10000001     20000000     40    
20000001     30000000     50
```

Comment: =IF(AND((VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$S$70,3,FALSE)) > VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$S$70,1,FALSE), VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$S$70,3,FALSE)) < VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$S$70,2,FALSE)), VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$S$70,3,FALSE), "")

Comment: I also realized you will need to use `INDEX-MATCH` to find the min and max values, but the above gives you the general idea, of using `=IF(AND()) logic.

Comment: I'd reccomend using index match. It's much easier

Comment: Thanks,   Guys! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the forth criterion to TRUE:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A2="","",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$S$70,3,TRUE)),"")
```

As long as the data is sorted on Column A in Ascending Order, the Max is not needed.  The VLOOKUP will find where it fits.

[image]

Comment: I would just like to point out that I find it funny that @John added a space before the "!" so he could have enough characters in his comment... :)